# Charging speeds between USB C/USB C and USB A/USB C

Tags: usb, charging, nexus-5x

I just bought the Anker power core 20100+ and it came with 2 cables.One Usb C to Usb C cable, and One Usb C to USB A.

I am just wondering which one would give me better charge speeds for my Nexus 5x or if it wouldn't matter at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your device comes with USB Type C which is equipped to handle higher power for charging and hence that is recommended over using the USB C to A conversion

[USB 3.1 – Type-C Connector](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_from_a_usb_port)

> ....Rather than using four-pins as in the classic type-A and type-B, the type-C connector has 24 pins and is reversible, meaning it can be plugged in either way. It supports 900mA and, on command, delivers 1.5A and 3.0A over a 5V power bus while streaming data. This results in 7.5 and 15 watt power consumption respectively, as opposed to 2.5W using the original USB (current times voltage = wattage)

Also see a decent comparison of  [Type C Charging](http://www.cnet.com/news/usb-type-c-one-cable-to-connect-them-all/)